# Is this trailing return type legal in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, trailing-return-type

The following:

```
auto (*f())() -> int;
```

gives an error in C++11 mode with Clang saying:

> error: 'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return
>   types are a C++14 extension

but compiles in C++14 mode. GCC compiles without complaining in both modes with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

n3337 7.1.6.4/2 says:

> The auto type-specifier may appear with a function declarator with a
>   trailing-return-type (8.3.5) in any context where such a declarator is
>   valid.

8.3.5p2 talks about function declarators but I'm too inexperienced to figure it out. Can anyone explain if it's legal in C++11?

Comment: Are you trying to specify a trailing return type for the function pointer `f` returns?

Comment: I would guess that GCC is right to compile it. Coliru's Clang and GCC both say it's a `int (*(*)())()`.

Comment: Regardless of whether the standard allowed it, it's pretty clearly a compiler bug too. An error message saying that a trailing return type is omitted when a trailing return type is present is a bad error message.

Comment: @chris Eh? That might be `&f`'s type, but not `f`'s, right?

Comment: @hvd, Yes, I used a trick of a compiler error with some `print_type(f);`, so it decayed.

Answer (score 4):

This is partly covered by [CWG 1725](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1725):

> The treatment of a declaration like the following is not clear:
>
> ```
> auto (*f())() -> int; // #1
> ```
>
> 8.3.5 [dcl.fct] paragraph 2 appears to require determining the type of the nested declarator
>
> ```
> auto (*f()); // #2
> ```
>
> which, because it does not have a
>   trailing-return-type, would be ill-formed by (C++11) 7.1.6.4
>   [dcl.spec.auto]. (In C++14, an auto return type without a
>   trailing-return-type is, of course, permitted.)
>
> **Rationale (September, 2013): The intent of the C++11 wording is that the requirement for a trailing return type applies only at the top level of the declarator to which auto applies, not to each possible recursive stage in the declarator processing.** [..]

Furthermore, according to [[dcl.fct]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#2),

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> `D1` `(` *parameter-declaration-clause* `)` [...] *trailing-return-type*
>
> **and the type of the contained *declarator-id* in the declaration `T D1` is “*derived-declarator-type-list* `T`”**, `T` shall be the single *type-specifier* `auto`.

As mentioned in the DR, `T D1` is `auto (*f())`, which is of type "function of `()` returning pointer to `auto`" (i.e. matches the requirement). Hence your code is valid in both C++11 and 14, and `f`'s type is "function of `()` returning pointer to function of `()` returning `int`".